# Sort elasticsearch based on other results

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I am building an application where a user is querying an ElasticSearch database of products based on a criteria and then I return the three best results. Part of "best" means that although the three results must match the criteria, I am trying to maximize the *differences* between them. For example, supposed each product has a color, size, and year and I do a query for all products with a year of "2013" and size "small" I don't want to see 3 blue products. I am trying to say "find three documents that match a criteria, but then try to maximize the differences in fields that are not in the criteria".

I suppose that I could solve this on the client side and return many more than three results and deal with it there, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can do it without returning more data than I need to. Perhaps ElasticSearch is not the right tool for the job here, and if that is the case: what is?

Comment: Does this mean that you want to exclude any product that has a color entry? Or is it that you want the user to specify `year:2013, size:small, color: NOT blue` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a bool query, similar to the following:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {            
        },
        "must_not" : {
            "term" : { "color" : "blue" }
        },
        "should" : [
            {
                "term" : { "year" : "2013" }
            },
            {
                "term" : { "size" : "small" }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1,
        "boost" : 1.0
    }
}
```

See the elasticsearch Query DSL for more info: 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query/